# C# редактирование XML файла

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

Использую классы `XmlReader` и `XmlWriter` для работы с XML и столкнулся с проблемой редактирования.

По сути, методы `XmlWriter` могут делать записи в XML, но он записывает их вместо всего, что там содержится, а нужно сделать так, чтобы при добавлении данных предыдущие оставались в файле.

Также делать записи в конкретном месте, а не в конце или в начале документа, поскольку может нарушиться структура XML. Ещё не совсем понятно, как можно удалить какой-нибудь тег и всё его содержимое из файла.

Прошу, пожалуйста, не советовать LINQ2XML.

Comment: Читаете из файла с помощью XmlReader. Пишете в _другой_ файл отредактированные данные с помощью XmlWriter. Потом первый файл удаляете, второй переименовываете.

Comment: `XmlWriter` — это устаревший API 20-летней давности. Целью является создание XML-документов с нуля. Для редактирования существующего XML-документа лучше использовать XSLT или LINQ to XML.

Comment: Ну что там, есть подвижки?

Comment: Ну вот к чему это? Я прекрасно знаю об XSLT и LINQ, и если я спросил про XmlWriter, то мне нужен именно он.

Comment: Да, разобрался. Просто, думал, что есть какие-то специальные методы, но оказалось, что нужно перезаписывать файл.

Comment: Не все видели ваш первый вопрос, поэтому не знают, чем обусловлено желание использовать потоковые средства. Поэтому желательно в каждом вопросе кратко описывать _всю_ релевантную информацию.

Comment: По поводу перезаписи файла: без этого никак не обойтись, будь то xml, json, плоский текст или любой другой формат данных. / Метод `ReadToFollowing` применили в своём коде?

Comment: Нет, не применял. Я вообще через условия выкручивался) Но мне сделали замечание по поводу этого и порекомендовали заменить мой костыль на более читаемый с использованием метода ReadToFollowing.